# MVC5 Where to put authentication forms in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

Following this title, in my web.config, it's generated by VS 2012.

Now, i don't know where i put the below code in web.config through i saw someone put it in `<system.web>` but in my web.config it have only `<system.web.webPages.razor>` and `<system.webServer>`. When i put this code somewhere in web.config I get an error at `<authentication mode="Forms">`:

There's code :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginurl="~/Comfirm/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: You are putting it in the wrong web.config file. There are two web.config files. one in `Views` Folder and one in the root of the site. put it in the system.web tag of the config file in the site root.

Comment: @Nkosi oh my god, 9:36 pm, my mistake. It's solved. Thanks so much !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are putting it in the wrong web.config file. There are two web.config files. one in `Views` Folder and one in the root of the site. put it in the `system.web` tag of the web.config file in the site root

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings  />
  <appSettings >
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>      

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Comfirm/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>

  <!--other configuration-->
<configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. My mistake !

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `<system.web>` to the config and put the authentication section [within it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginurl="~/Comfirm/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I try, but I get an error : It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Have you added it to the web.config in the root of the app?

Comment: uhm, i added after <configuration> tag

Comment: @user1465351 no. it is suppose to be within the configuration tag `configuration > system.web > authentication > forms`

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, it within configuration

Comment: @user1465351 update the question with more of the config file and where you put the authentication. You may not have formatted the file properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. this problem is solved. I put this code in wrong file web.config. T_T

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistaken, VS only makes the tags it will use. Have you tried creating `<system.web>`? It won't auto generate empty sections to the config.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginurl="~/Comfirm/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I try, but I get an error : It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: @user1465351 If you're getting that error, you're using the wrong `web.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

in MVC 5 the default value is :

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
  type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
 Microsoft.AI.Web" />
 </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

You can notice the Line

```
  <authentication mode="None" />
```

Change it to :

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1440" />
</authentication>
```

And timeout="1440" its Mean one day

Comment: I liked the **important** part that says: `in MVC 5 the default value is` and more specifically about the `<authentication mode="None" />` line.