# ASP.NET MVC - Custom authentication doen't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I have created a simple authentication form to authenticate user using `FormsAuthentication`.

This is how I have used it

```
public ActionResult LoginUser(Login login)
        {
            //var encodedPassword = HashPassword.Decode(login.Password);
            var encodedPassword = login.Password;
            var loginData = context.Accounts.Where(p => p.Username == login.Username && p.Password == encodedPassword).SingleOrDefault();

            if (loginData != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, false);


                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["errMess"] = "Invalid credential";
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
```

Now I have a code to get a logged in username in _layout.cshtml

```
<div class="profile_info">
   <span>
      Welcome,
      @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
         @Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)
      }else {
         <strong>Hello worlds</strong>
      }
    </span>
</div>
```

but this doesn't solve my problem
What am I doing wrong or am I missing something please help me I am new in `dot net`
Thanks!

Comment: What's your problem then? Is that the username not displayed or something else? Please explain what thing doesn't work, also consider using `Membership` or `Identity` provider instead of custom-made authentication.

Comment: I was unable to get logged in username and also `Authorize` doesn't work in controller

Comment: Do you have an auth cookie maybe????try checking if an auth cookie is created, if not , change the necessary settings in the web.config

Comment: @mahlatse - auth cookies is created in the format of `E63C9EC8287A32E7CCB8A98B88345EBDCB0B01E2E1F0D731EECC407CCD648C8388468CD922A73C1C08C48091066E6028B25D58391DCE5E837010959ED7AC9A2176616C4985BBB80E6738EAFCE7BEA3C3E1ABB68C4927BA8C04CCCF6DC8A051168A4A9960496025C9E2C8788ADA03BC1F`. How to change setting in `web.config`

Comment: Make sure that client browser had enabled cookies, also use `<authentication mode="Forms">`. The `User.Identity.Name` property retrieve its value from request cookie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC5 Where to put authentication forms in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393787/mvc5-where-to-put-authentication-forms-in-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

inside `<system.web>` section in `web.config`